# Re-use SaveAs function on file that is saved as HHMMSS in filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file saving as:

```
wbkVer.SaveAs fileName:=folderPath & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy_hhmmss") & "_Compare.xlsx"
```

However, I need to do other logic and then save it to that same filename again.  I can't find a means to do that without it saving it with hhmmss again.   Is there any way to capture the filename as above and put that into a variable, so it's not assigning the hhmmss to it again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just construct the file name you want in a variable first and use that to save, then re-use later.

```
dim name as string
name = folderPath & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy_hhmmss") & "_Compare.xlsx"
wbkVer.SaveAs fileName:=name
' now you still have name around to re-use later
```

Having said this, if you need to save the same thing under the same name, once you've done `wbkVer.SaveAs` the first time, can't you just use `wbkVer.Save` subsequently?

Comment: I thought I had tried the .save and it saved it by mmddyy again, but now I'm questioning if I did or not.  Either way, this works - thanks!